# Is it possible to send data from visualforce page to lightning component?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, visualforce-component

I am currently using a visualforce page inside a lightning component.Is there any way to set the parent lightning component attribute from visualforce page or send data to the lightning component from visualforce page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only official mechanism for this sort of communication is the [Lightning Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel).

Note that you cannot directly embed a Visualforce page within an LWC. The best you can do is to use an iframe with the URL for a Visualforce page inside the LWC.

However, since URLs for the two different types of page (lightning vs visuallforce) cannot be programmatically determined within the same context due to a lack of any API to do so, I strongly recommend against such an approach and feel you should simply include both a Visualforce page and an LWC that interacts with that page via LMS in the same Lightning Page. I.e. the components are simply siblings on the page.

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand, I am trying to use visualforce inside the aura component, not the other way around.

Comment: Apologies, I initially misread your question. Answer updated.